# How do I repeat a symbol in the legend of a ggplot to gain a better view of the symbol?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, symbols

I have just started the du Bois challenge as part of #tidytuesday, and am on challenge 1: Comparative Increase of White and Colored Population in Georgia

The original graph has the "WHITE" symbol with 4 dashes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3itS.png), but when I replicate the plot, the legend only has 1 and a bit of the second dash.

How do I repeat the symbol in the legend to get 4 dashes? I don't need to increase the size, just the repetition

Comment: The question is not reproducible, [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: You could try to increase the width of the legend key, e.g. `guides(linetype = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(50, "pt")))`

Comment: @stefan Care to post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `legend.key.width` in `theme`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, linetype = f)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "strwidth", "- - - - "))
```

[image]

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2021)
df1 <- data.frame(
 x = c(1:10, 1:10),
 y = c(cumsum(rnorm(10)), cumsum(rnorm(10))),
 f = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the approach by @RuiBarradas but making use of `guide_legend` to set the `keywidth` you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = psavert, linetype = "psavert")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = uempmed, linetype = "uempmed")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(psavert = 1, uempmed = 5)) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(50, "pt"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]